# How to calculate radiative transition rate of exciton in a quantum dot with specific dimension?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-optics, nanoscience

I am writing rate equations for a nanophotonic system including three quantum dots. I need to calculate that radiative transition rates of exciton in ground state in those quantum dots.
In the paper named "[Dynamics of ONF-Based Three-QD Nanophotonic
AND Gates at Finite Temperatures](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5689400)", table1, there are the exact numbers for radiative transition rates but it is not clear how it is calculated! Does anyone here know it?

Comment: This seems like an interesting question, but that paper appears to be behind a paywall. It will be hard for anyone w/o a IEEE membership to deal with the question, and it won't be helpful for others visiting this site in the future. Could you add a basic description of the system and add a snippet of this mythical "table 1" to your question?

Comment: That table just shows the radiative transition rate of exciton for QD1, QD2 and QD3 having 1e9, 2.83e9 and 8e9 (1/s).

Comment: Generally, with quantum systems whose quantum states are understood, and overlap integrals (aka matrix elements) can be computed, radiative transistions can be caculated with Fermi's Golden Rule.  What is your level of familiarity with this?

Comment: I computed energy levels of exciton in cubic quantum dot but it seems I should compute hamiltonian to be abe to use fermi golden rule. Is it right?